Correspondence between the Ising model considering vacancy and lattice gas
Several textbooks discuss the equivalence between the Ising model and the lattice gas. However, I have never seen a textbooks/article that discuss the correspondence between the Ising model with vacancy, i.e., a model that consider spin up, spin down and an empty site, with the lattice gas. Is there a way to relate these models?

You need to say more precisely how you define your lattice gas model. The standard one has only 2 states per site (occupied and empty) and thus cannot be related to the Ising model with vacancies which has 3 states per site. Of course, one can consider generalizations of the lattice gas with more states per site. A trivial one would have two species of particles (+ empty sites) and then you could take the trivial mapping sending vacancies to empty sites, and $+$, resp. $-$, spins to the first, resp. the second, species.

Sure, the Blume-Capel model can be used to describe alloy for example (you can google blume capel model alloy)
